# Revert from SQL Server 2017 to 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2017

I would like to know how do I completely remove all installation for SQL Server 2017 and revert to 2008 R2?

I have attempted update of service by point to 2008 R2 install but no luck.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? What does "update of service" mean. Please explain what you did in detail and any error messages you encountered. Are you trying to uninstall SQL 2017 server? or are you trying to point a client application at SQL 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to downgrade your SQL Server version. You must uninstall 2017 and install 2008R2.

If you want to keep the data, you need to export it in some flat files, because once attached to newer server version, a database is upgraded and cannot be attached to an older one. Even restoring a backup made with newer version is not possible. The other option you have is to install 2008R2 and use [import/export wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017) to copy the data from 2017 to 2008R2. After you transfered your data, you can [uninstall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/uninstall-an-existing-instance-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-2017) the existing 2017 instance.